# How to edit "Not enough units.." error message in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Is there a chance to edit this error message

`"Not enough units of %s are available in stock to fulfil this order."`

somehow with a hook?

---

This comes from the the code which I found in the [ReserveStock.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/src/Checkout/Helpers/ReserveStock.php#L188) file, from the WooComerce plugin.

Full code:

```php
if ( ! $result ) {
    $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
    throw new ReserveStockException(
        'woocommerce_product_not_enough_stock',
        sprintf(
            /* translators: %s: product name */
            __( 'Not enough units of %s are available in stock to fulfil this order.', 'woocommerce' ),
            $product ? $product->get_name() : '#' . $product_id
        ),
        403
    );
}
```

Comment: The text content of the message is sent through the [translation function `__`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__/) here, so using the usual WP translation mechanisms, you should be able to “translate” it into something else, even for the original language English. If you are not familiar with how translating such text content coming from plugins works in WP, then you’ll have to do a bit of reading up on that though. Loco Translate is one of the popular plugins to add translations, a rough guide can be found here, https://localise.biz/wordpress/plugin/custom-translations

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated, so I start reading :D